# WPF binding button

Tags: wpf, binding

I have two buttons in my application

Now I want to bind the btnOff to !isOn. Meaning is btnOn is Enabled, btnOff should be Disabled and vice-versa

EDIT: Below is my implementation:

```
<Button x:Name="btnOn" Content="On" Width="45" Height="24" IsEnabled="{Binding isOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverter}}" />
   <Button x:Name="btnOff" Content="Off" Width="45" Height="24" IsEnabled="{Binding isOn} />

 public class BoolInverterConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return !(bool)value;
            }
            return value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I implemented Converter to invert the boolean value and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to have another computed/derived property IsOff (no backing field) that negates the IsOn property ?

```
public bool IsOn{ 
  get{...}
  set
  {    _isOn = value; 
       NotifyPropertyChanged("IsOn");
       NotifyPropertyChanged("IsOff");
  }
}

public bool IsOff
{
   get{   return !IsOn;}
}
```

Converters are normally used to convert data types e.g. to bind a Visibility enum property to a boolean backing property in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

[Element data binding](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/element_to_element_data_binding_pg1.htm),

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part-1  -> another example for element data binding